# how to organize 50 or more html forms using css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

im facing a big a problem regarding how to organize about 50 or form in 1 page
its a simple forms which will allow use to save username and passwords for about 50 or more website
i need some ideas in how to organize them so they look fine and not messed also its become faster when loading the page 
i think i can use css and Jquery for such propose but i would like to have some ideas about it must look ?
should i use div and grouping them in multi groups ?
should i use filedset which will not give me the web 2.0 look ?

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

i just need some good ideas also if there is a good tutorial in how to design a simple web 2.0 look login box that would be so nice

Comment: you can restyle `filedset`s for that "web 2.0" look if you want :-)

Comment: What are the 50 forms? It's kind of hard to understand what you are asking, but is it username and password for 50 or x amount of websites? Do you think that people would use the same username and password for most of these websites?

Comment: Thats not really a programming, but more a design question. Also, I can't imagine where you want to use/have a need of JS.

Comment: no id on't think so or better to say i don't know :)

Comment: @feeela i was thinking in creating a simple login box for each site it will be hidden and when user click the site title then the login box appear

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with or without filedset. It is up to you.

You can restyle fieldset to anything you want.

```
fieldset{
  border:none;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your forms are collecting the same info (username/password), then just design one form that contains the following:

- username field
- password field
- < select > drop-down containing values for the various sites for which you are saving data.

Allow the user to select the site from the drop-down and use the same set of input fields to do their work.